# What kind of graph is this?

Tags: data-visualization, definition, boxplot

I came across the following graph in a report where the authors report the results of a Monte Carlo simulation study in terms of proportions. I have never seen such kind of plots before. Does anyone know the name of this type of plots?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a non-standard use of violin plot:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot

Comment: Thanks, indeed they resemble violin plots. Is it possible to get such a homogeneous shape with violin plots? In my mind I always picture them as wiggly boxplots.

Comment: It is possible.Violin plot is for having multiple distributions simultaneously. It is possible that some distributions are U-shaped instead of the normal normal/Gaussian distribution like. No matter the shape, violin plots can be used, although the use is not a standard, if it does not look like a violin.